# jquery - how to show elements with data attribute equal to value of array

Tags: jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create a filter plugin,
after the init and other functions i got two arrays

```
foo1=[test,test2,test3]
foo2=[test,test3]
```

now i must show the elements with the data attribute tin foo2 that are equal to the clicked elements data attribute that are in foo1

this is my code for this :

```
r$.each($FILTER.foo2elem, function() {
var elemfoo2 = $(this).data();
var elemfoo2data = $(this).data().foo2elem.split(' ');

r$.each($FILTER.foo1saved, function(i, selectedFilters) {
    if ($.inArray(selectedFilters, elemfoo2data) !== -1) {
        console.log(selectedFilters + ' è uguale a ' + elemfoo2data);
        console.log('show element with foo2 data equal to foo1');
        //how can i hook that element
    } else {
        console.log('hide');
        //how hide other element
    }
})
```

});

please help me, and i'm sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filter function and then return item if that object found in another array. I like to use it as this one can be compared with any object. Good luck.

```js
$(function() {
  var foo1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  var bar1 = ['one', 'three'];

  var rr = foo1.filter(function(index) {
    return jQuery.inArray(index, bar1) != -1;
  });

  console.log(rr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```